# Query function syntax in google sheets for concat a cell with date format to search in a date range. Error: #VALUE! Unable to parse

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Good night everybody!

I need help, I am using the syntax that people are teatching in youtube and in the manuals but isn't working at all, please help me guys, follow aditional informations:

```
=QUERY('PERDA REAL'!$A:$J;"SELECT D WHERE A = Date '"&B6&"'";0)
```

Cell B6: The format of the this cell is YYY-MM-DD

Range PERDA REAL: The format of the this range is YYY-MM-DD

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Sheets, dates get converted into numbers when concatenating to a string, even if you see the `yyyy-mm-dd` format on the cell. You can check that by using:

```
="The raw value is: " & B6
```

The way of getting the date in the format you like, is to format the date as string yourself. You can do so by using `TEXT`:

```
="The formatted value is: " & TEXT(B6; "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

### References

- [TEXT (Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY('PERDA REAL'!A:J; "select D where A = date '"&TEXT(B6; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"; 0)
```